# Run an external program from a QT Pushbutton

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I have created a main Window with one Pushbutton in QT and when I try to run an additional small program when the Pushbutton is clicked, it doesn't work. I have the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start("/home/helloworld.out");
}
```

I am working with Linux. Any ideas what could happend? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"Any ideas what could happend?"_ - Based on your description it sounds like your kajigger is out of alignment.

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Can you check the status of process? [see the error enum http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html]

Comment: Do you have permission to execute some file in the `/home` folder ?, usually with the default user you can only access `/home/$USER`

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. Is it a problem related to a bad signal/slot connection, i.e. `on_pushButton_clicked` or a `QProcess` problem?

Comment: I posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for `QProcess` some days ago: [SO: Creating QT Application as GUI for existing console-based application on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45209503/7478597)

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your process and then promptly returning. If you are not planning on connecting any signals from the `QProcess` you could just statically allocate it to save yourself from using `deleteLater`.

Try something like this.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess process;;

    process.start("~/helloworld.out");
    process.waitForStarted();
    process.waitForFinished();
    process.close();
}
```

I'll step out on a limb and suggest maybe you did not mean  `/home/helloworld.out` but `~/helloworld.out`. In any case check the path exists as well.