# Track the script execution progress in the progressBar Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In my program, I run the execution of a `Python` script:

```
void analysis::on_pB_start_clicked()
{
    QString file = ui->lE_path->text();
    if (file.size() == 0)
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "warning", "");
        return;
    }
    QProcess analyse;
    QString cArg;
    cArg="/tmp/pixmap.py -f " + file;
    analyse.start("python3 "+cArg);
    analyse.waitForFinished();
    analyse.close();
}
```

This process is running in the background and I can't track the execution `time` of this process.

Please tell me how I can track the execution of this script through the `progressBar` in `Qt` on the program `form`?

I think that in the `Python script` being run, me need to draw conclusions at some stage of the `code`, for example, `Print ("1")`, `Print ("2")`, and so on, and track these conclusions in your program and pass them to the `progressBar`, but these are just my assumptions... I could be wrong... please tell me how to act correctly and productively in this case.

`And yet`, when executing the above code, the program window `freezes (waiting)` for the duration of the execution of this `script`.

In the `Python script`, I use the `matplotlib.pyplot` library, and it is called there several times, several `graphs` are created and saved to a directory, which in the next I use these graphs in my `Qt` program.

Comment: `analyse.waitForFinished();` is blocking, so freeze ui, as your function is for ui from its name.

Comment: @Jarod42, I understand this, without this the script process will `not start`.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Creating QT Application as GUI for existing console-based application on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45209503/7478597)